# radbuttontelerik/winform/c#: how to remove border of the icon?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radbuttontextbox

I have this searcher

[image]

I would like to remove the border of the glass.

It is a **RadButtonTextBox** in **Winform** in **c#**.

I thried modifing the colors of textbox and I didn't get what I need:

```
this.radtxtFilter.RightButtonItems[0].EnableBorderHighlight = false;
this.radtxtFilter.RightButtonItems[0].BorderHighlightColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property ShouldPaint is the answer:

```
RadButtonElement radButtonElement = new RadButtonElement();
radButtonElement.ImagePrimitive.Image = Resources.TV_search;
radButtonElement.BorderElement.ShouldPaint = false;
this.radtxtFilter.RightButtonItems.Add(radButtonElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to eliminate the border around the right button element is to manipulate its Visibility property:

```
        RadButtonElement radButtonElement = new RadButtonElement();
        radButtonElement.Text = "";
        radButtonElement.DisplayStyle = Telerik.WinControls.DisplayStyle.Text;
        radButtonElement.TextElement.CustomFont = "TelerikWebUI";
        radButtonElement.TextElement.CustomFontSize = 10;

        radButtonElement.BorderElement.Visibility = ElementVisibility.Collapsed;

        this.radButtonTextBox1.RightButtonItems.Add(radButtonElement);
```

[image]